Is there a more concise way to register deeply-nested special dependencies in .NET ServiceCollection?
In an ASP.NET web service I have my ordinary dependencies, e.g.
services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomerCreationService, CustomerCreationService>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomerValidationService, CustomerValidationService>();
...

But then we have just a few that are special, that only in a certain context do we want an exception to the above, so I have to do the following.  In this example, I want to use an EmailService instantiated differently than usual whenever I need a new IEmailService in the context of a CustomerService, rather than using the "default" instance registered above, so I need to do the following :
services.AddTransient<ICustomerService>(sp =>
  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<CustomerService>(sp,
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ICustomerValidationService>(sp,
      ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ICustomerCreationService>(sp,
        // this is the only override we actually need (don't use scoped IEmailService)
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<IEmailService>(sp => new EmailService(specialConfigurationString)
      )
    )
  )
);

Now here ICustomerValidationService doesn't need its own activation; I just want it to use the ordinary dependency injection registered above.  Same for ICustomerCreationService.  But when I want a dependency of a dependency of a dependency to be special, like IEmailService here, I think I have to specify arguments for the whole tree using ActivatorUtilities, right? Is there a more elegant way?  I'd love to be above to say something like this, but I don't see any way.  Have I missed it?
services.AddTransient<CustomerService>(sp =>
  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstanceAtAnyLevel<EmailService>(sp) // I wish...
);


I didn't quite get it; is the EmailService the BackgroundService requires some different implementation to the normal EmailService?

No, it just needs to be new for every instance (e.g. just like transient), rather than Scoped.

Why's that then?

Because a background service doesn't have a scope (for reasons that are beyond the point of this question), and .NET throws an exception if it attempts to create a scoped instance. However, the same question would apply if I needed a different implementation, in which case I'd want to do something like services.AddTransient<IBackgroundService>(_ =>   ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstanceAtAnyLevel<IEmailService>(_ => new SpecialEmailService()));, but I don't see a way yet.

A background service can just create its own scope inside the execute method.

"Because a background service doesn't have a scope (for reasons that are beyond the point of this question". I think your question is an XY problem. The real question probably is: "how can I ensure that my background service runs in a scope in [special condition]".

I'd actually like to know how to register "special" dependencies without specifying the whole tree.  The background worker is irrelevant.  I will edit the question to avoid the apparent red herring.

I'm not sure, but maybe this can help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
public sealed class BackgroundService: IHostedService, IDisposable
{
public BackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    var emailService = services.GetRequiredService<IEmailService>();
    
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    serviceScope.Dispose();
}

}

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

I'd actually like to know how to register "special" dependencies without specifying the whole tree. The background worker is irrelevant. I will edit the question to avoid the apparent red herring.


Because a background service doesn't have a scope

Then it should create one. If you are actually using background hosted services then the usual approach is to create one per iteration and resolve the dependency (docs). Something along these lines:
public class MyBackgroundService(IServiceProvider services) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (...)
        {
            using var scope = services.CreateScope();
            var customerService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomerService>();

            await customerService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

If you have something different the same approach can be used:
services.AddTransient<BackgroundService>(sp => sp.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomerService>());

Note that this implementation has at least one potential big problem that it will not dispose correctly owned dependencies (if any are disposable, like EF Core context). This can be workaround by making the registered dependency disposable and capturing scope in it or making wrapper (see for example this answer, basically following factory approach).
P.S.
Note that the check for a scope (by default is applied only for development environments and can be disabled if needed) is there for a reason. If you are creating a scoped service outside of the scope you can end up with so called captive dependency which can have negative effects on the app (for example in case of EF context - degrading performance and memory-leakish behaviour).

I'd actually like to know how to register "special" dependencies without specifying the whole tree. The background worker is irrelevant. I will edit the question to avoid the apparent red herring.

@PatrickSzalapski this shows how to resolve the whole tree. If this is not suitable - please provide more info/[mre] showing what exactly is the problem.

It is suitable; I was just asking if there is a more elegant way where one doesn't have to specify every level of the tree redundantly.

@PatrickSzalapski I was talking about the one I have suggested. Also check out the added P.S. note in the answer.

I don't need or want to create a scope.  I want to add a special transient dependency only when in the context of a different parent object as I stated in the original question.  Thank you for trying, though, your answer seems wise but for a different question.

@PatrickSzalapski but it is answer for your question though. If you want easier way to create object graph - just create a scope and resolve the root dependency from it (as shown in the answer) and let the service provider handle the rest. If you don't want to create a scope or there are reasons why you can't - then AFAIK there is not much you can do except for manually resolving everything as you do in the question itself.
